# Tkinter Python 3 - Labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a revision quiz program using Tkinter. The program will automatically get questions from an array and then output the questions using a Label. When the submit button is pressed, the program will check the answer and then should update the Label to the next question in the array but it doesn't, there is no error message. The score is updated but the Label just doesn't update.

```
def entryQuestion():

    entryOpen = open('./files/entry.csv','r')
    entryFile = csv.reader(entryOpen, delimiter = ',')

    global entryQuestionArray
    entryQuestionArray = []
    for topic, question, answer in entryFile:
        for i in range(0,1):
            entryQuestionArray.append(question)

    entryQuestionArray = random.sample(entryQuestionArray, len(entryQuestionArray))

    arrayLength = len(entryQuestionArray)

    for x in entryQuestionArray:
        global qOut
        qOut = x
        global entryQuestion
        entryQuestion = Label(entryQ, text = x)
        entryQuestion.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        global answerEntry
        answerEntry = StringVar()
        global answerEntryBox
        answerEntryBox = Entry(entryQ, textvariable = answerEntry)
        answerEntryBox.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        submitEntryAnswer = Button(entryQ, text = 'Submit Answer', command = entryQuestionCheck)
        submitEntryAnswer.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

def entryQuestionCheck():
    entryOpen = open('./files/entry.csv','r')
    entryFile = csv.reader(entryOpen, delimiter = ',')
    tempScore = score
    for topic, question, answer in entryFile:
        if qOut == question:
            if answerEntry.get() == answer:
                tempScore = tempScore + 1
            else:
                tempScore = tempScore +  0

    return
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The result I get every time is 14, I've have no idea why, I've never come across the line you told me to put into my code, could you explain why I get 14 as a result all the time

Comment: Thanks for your help, if anyone could offer more guidance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create the label, entry, and button once and forget the for loop.  The first question will be put on the Label when it is created.  Every time the user presses the button (calls the function), that function will set a new question on the label and clear the Entry box.  See the set option at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

Answer (score 0):

Each Widget only needs 1 call, on the top or in a main class, you need to call him only once:

```
class MainPage(#values):
    self.label1 = tk.Label(self, #values)
```

and in the function, if you need to change your values, for example the text, you only need to pass self values to function, and change him, like this:

```
def changeValues(self):
    self.label["text"] = "the text that u want to put in"
```

or:

```
def changeValues(label):
    label["text"] = "the text that u want to put in"
```

and in the main class, or in the scope, you need to call the function with the values, if is in the scope (not in a class) you need to pass the widget in the values:

```
class MainPage(#values):
    self.label1 = tk.Label(self, #values)
    changeValues(self)
```

or:

```
label1 = tk.Label(self, #values)
changeValues(label1)
```